# get values from json

Tags: python, facebook, json

I have problem with accessing values in json:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": "",
     "from": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
     },
     "picture": "",
     "source": "",
     "height": 480,
     "width": 720,
     "images": [
        {
           "height": 1365,
           "width": 2048,
           "source": ""
        },
```

I wanto to get all images source: `albums['data']['images']` but sth goes wrong, I have troubles with nested dictionaries. Please help

Comment: What exception do you get? It looks like this is an incomplete piece of JSON, which is a likely problem.

Comment: What goes wrong? How are you trying to access the value? There is nothing special about nested dictionaries.

Comment: this is json from facebook, I posted only piece of it, it's long

Comment: Have you looked at the jsonpath module? http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ This module simplifies extracting json data.

Answer (score 2):

```
"data": [
  {
```

The `"data"` field's value is not a dictionary, but rather a *list* of dictionaries.

Try `albums['data'][0]['images']` instead, and so on for the other items in the list, or similarly, a loop:

```
for item in album['data']:
    # do something with item['images']
```

Comment: meh what poster said should still apply though :)

Comment: @donatello: Do some basic debugging. Either set breakpoints or print out the content of the variable. Then examine its structure and see which keys/indexes are available and access that one. Print out the next level, etc.

Comment: @FelixKling Whoops. This is what I get for answering multiple questions in a day. :) Fixed loop example to correct language.